# Php calling functions that store values globally doesn't return desired value

Tags: php

For starters, I have to do it this way in my code so I'm not looking for a completely 'different' solution.
Why is this not storing/returning the value I entered to the global variables?

EDIT: I forgot to put the if inside a function so assigning 'wrong' goes globally anyway.
This is a working one.

```
<?php
$track;$cat;$title;

function storeData($track, $cat, $title){
    $GLOBALS['track']=$track;
    $GLOBALS['cat']=$cat;
    $GLOBALS['title']=$title;
    print 'inside function:';
    print $GLOBALS['track'];
    print $GLOBALS['cat'];
    print $GLOBALS['title'];
    return array($GLOBALS['track'],$GLOBALS['cat'],$GLOBALS['title']);
}

function getData($track, $cat, $title){
    return array('track'=>$GLOBALS['track'],'cat'=>$GLOBALS['cat'],'title'=>$GLOBALS['title']);
}

$a=1;
if ($a==1) {
    test($a);
}

function test($a){
    $track='correct track ';
    $cat='correct cat ';
    $title='correct title ';
    storeData($track, $cat, $title);
    print 'storing this data:';
    print $track;
    print $cat;
    print $title;
    $cat='wrong'; $track='wrong'; $title='wrong';
    $getting=getData();
    $t=$getting['track'];
    $c=$getting['cat'];
    $e=$getting['title'];
    print 'reading back this data:';
    print $t;
    print $c;
    print $e;
}
?>
```

Output:

```
inside function:correct track correct cat correct title 
storing this data:correct track correct cat correct title 
reading back this data:correct track correct cat correct title
```

Comment: Oh wait, I want to override the current $track, $cat, $title values from getData to print it.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid, check out my answer here.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay he is already automatically notified that your answer was posted, you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: @sidyll, thank you for notifying.

Answer (score 1):

When you return array from the function, you should assigned back the local variables with the returned $GLOBALS values. Like this

```
$cat='wrong'; $track='wrong'; $title='wrong';
$returned_array = getData($track, $cat, $title);//read global var
$track = $returned_array[0];
$cat = $returned_array[1];
$title = $returned_array[2];
// then you print these variables

print 'reading back this data:';
print $track;
print $cat;
print $title;
```

Comment: For some reason it prints blank instead (after 'reading back this data:').

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid, I have updated my answer. Thank you for pointing that out sidyll.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `getData()` returns an array but you never used the returned value, which is what contains the correct data. And in this case you actually don't need arguments at all:

```
function getData()
{
    return [
        $GLOBALS['track'],
        $GLOBALS['cat'],
        $GLOBALS['title']
    ];
}

$data = getData();

$track = $data[0];
$cat   = $data[1];
$title = $data[2];
```

Or use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), for a neater assignment:

```
list($track, $cat, $title) = getData();
```

If however you want the function to assign to variables by itself, note that PHP functions are pass-by-value by default. So when you pass the arguments, you're passing a copy of their values. To pass-by-reference, you can do something like this:

```
function getData(&$track, &$cat, &$title)
{
    $track = $GLOBALS['track'];
    $cat   = $GLOBALS['cat'];
    $title = $GLOBALS['title'];
}

getData($track, $cat, $title);
```

This will modify the variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not saving the variables that the function getData returns.

```
$cat='wrong'; $track='wrong'; $title='wrong';
getData($track, $cat, $title);
print 'reading back this data:';
print $track;
print $cat;
print $title;
```

You are just calling the function but not saving the variables it's returning.